# Mock open using context manager and get the argument of open

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

first of all, sorry if this has been answered before but I have been looking all over the place and could not find anything.

I have a function that does this (in summary):

```
def func(path):
  with open(path) as f:
    json.load(f)
```

I want to unit test it and what I would like is that when I use open as context manager, `f` is the name of the argument I passed to open. The issue I am having is that I cannot mock the enter method in the proper module, it breaks everytime. This is whay I am doing so far:

```
def setUp(self):
    # Setup the content of the config files for the tests
    json.load = MagicMock(side_effect=file_content)

    # Opening a file returns the name of the file
    builtins.open = MagicMock(side_effect=lambda x: x) #1
    builtins.open.__enter__ = MagicMock(side_effect=builtins.open.return_value) #2
```

the MagicMock number 1 does what I expect it to do, when I run open("test") it returns "test". Nonetheless I cannot mock **enter** to return whatever I passed to open, it always fails with `AttributeError: __enter__`. I have tried also doing

```
builtins.open.return_value.__enter__ = MagicMock...
```

with no luck. Can anyone think on a way that this can be achieved? I have seen how to mock magic methods and I have thought I was comfortable with unittest mocking but in this case I cannot find a fitting solution. Thanks!

Comment: in this situation `__enter__` should be returning itself so it should be returning `builtins.open` which you define on the line above. if you wish to set a return value then do it on that variable

Answer (score 3):

I got it!

I had to define the side_effect dinamically but seems to be working fine. This is what I did:

```
def setUp(self):
    # Setup the content of the config files for the tests
    json.load = MagicMock(side_effect=file_content)

    # Opening a file returns the name of the file
    def get_mock_context(filename):
        mock_context = MagicMock()
        mock_context.__enter__.return_value = filename
        mock_context.__exit__.return_value = False
        return mock_context
    builtins.open = MagicMock(side_effect=get_mock_context)
```

In this way, the returned value is a mock that has the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods returning exactly the filename I passed to the call of open.